# Что такое plain-php

Tags: php

Приветствую всех вошедших

Есть такая штука joomla - если не знаешь что это такое -> гугл = знаешь.
Есть такая штука MODX - если не знаешь что это такое -> гугл = знаешь, тут правда немного сложнее, т.к. название может перекликаться не только с ним

Сейчас пошло такое модное словечко сайт на 'plain php'.. ребят, это что за чудо? Фреймворк, CMS ? Может кто объяснить?

p.s. развелось всякой неведомой хрени.. наболело

Comment: попробуйте погуглить перевод слова **plain**, вероятно это наведет вас на мысли

Answer (score 8):

Наверное, имеется в виду чистый php, без фреймворков и CMS. Т.е. ужасный самопис с дырами в безопасности, без поддержки и обновлений. Удобства на улице. : )

Comment: черт возьми, все так просто )